# Close vote queue limit VS vote close from question

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

Today, I notice something I never see before:
I open the close votes queues and they were a lot of them, so I start vote closing and the queue was very long this morning so I ended up with a message saying something like that:

> You've reach your daily limit in close vote review

So I though I couldn't vote to close for the all day but in fact I still can directly from any question.
Is this an intended behaviour to not allow review queue ? or is it a bug and I shouldn't be able to vote close for the day.
In my opinion the second one and it would be a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is intended behavior. It is a way of stopping "robo reviewers", people who go through the queues and just click blindly in order to get a badge (yes, this actually exists).

You can still close questions when you find them since that isn't something you can do blindly, so it can't be an abuse of the close queues.

Comment: Wow.. So there's people collecting badges for badges ? I think i get 99% of my badges out of luck :D And I can't even sell them like steam items making them pretty worthless ... Well Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Up to [24 votes per day](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)